# How to send parameter using body?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM mobilefirst adapter to get data from server in my windows phone 8.1 application.  when I am invoking the worklight adapter using c# code, my parameters are visible in url, however I want to send it as body. How to achieve this?

Following code I use for invoking adapter.

```
WLProcedureInvocationData invocationData = new WLProcedureInvocationData("CreditCardAdapter", "getAllRegisterCard", true);
            //invocationData.setParameters(new Object[] { custId, version });
            Object[] parameter = { custId, version };
            String myContextObject = "InvokingAdapterProceduresWP8";
            invocationData.setParameters(parameter);
            WLRequestOptions options = new WLRequestOptions();
            WLClient.getInstance().invokeProcedure(invocationData, new AllRegisterCardsInvokeListener(), options);
```

Comment: What Worklight version are you using?

Comment: i am using worklight 7.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement cannot be achieved using MFPF 7.1 native C# Silverlight SDK.

However, this can be achieved using WLResourceRequest API that is available in MFPF 7.1 native Windows Universal SDK.For details, refer to the API documentation available [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v710/mfpf_csharp_win8_native_client_api.pdf).

Comment: I want to invoke worklight adapter and WLResourceRequest API ask for URL only not adapter name . so can you please post sample code for invoking worklight adapter from windows universal?

Comment: I usede WLResourceRequest API also to send request but still parameters visible in URL only not in body.

following is code :

 WLResourceRequest req = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/CreditCardAdapter/registerCard", WLResourceRequest.GET);
                Dictionary<string, string> para = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                para.Add("uniqueReqNo", uniqueReqNo);
                para.Add("priCardNo", priCardNo);
                 req.setQueryParameters(para);
                RegisterInvokeListener listener = new RegisterInvokeListener();
                req.send(listener);

Comment: 1) Sample code :
 https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-windows-8-applications/

2) Review the API documentation. You will notice overloaded "send" methods. Use the one appropriate to your requirement

Comment: WLResourceRequest req = new  WLResourceRequest req("/adapters/CreditCardAdapter/registerCard", WLResourceRequest.POST);                                          Dictionary<string, string> para = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                para.Add("uniqueReqNo", uniqueReqNo);
              RegisterInvokeListener();
                req.send(para, new RegisterInvokeListener());

Comment: i Used following code for invoke adapter as per the document you had shared, parameters are send in body only but i didnt get response from server , my onsucces and on failure methods are nt going to called after invoking adapter. Aboveis code i had use

Comment: What errors do you see in the server logs? Try running Wireshark to see if the request is reaching the server and if server is responding

Comment: I am getting error code 500 and internal server error . but this works fine with " WLProcedureInvocationData " API only thing is using this API all parameter are send with the URL only and for security reson i want those parameter in body.